# Javascript Es6 default export

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, export

I just want to double check since I am trying to do this ES6 export default:

```
var Member = function(){}
export {
    Member as default
 };
```

JShint is error-ing out with this syntax (es6 enabled) but I thought it was valid. 
Is this really invalid or what is a valid way for writing a default export with the export syntax as

```
 export {
    Member 
 };
```

I was using this as reference: http://www.2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html
The example they gave was:

```
//------ module1.js ------
export default 123;
//------ module2.js ------
const D = 123;
export { D as default };
```

Why is this module2's 2nd line valid? (or is it?)

Comment: `export default Member`

Comment: How about if I were exporting multiple things with the export syntax last?

Comment: To post code, indent by 4 spaces (or use the {} button), don't use the \` character. Ah, Barmar has done it for you.

Comment: Does it work for your local transpiler/es6 environment while only jshint is bitching?

Comment: What is the exact error message of jshint?

Comment: Running "jshint:features" (jshint) task
/member.js
    330 |        Member as default
                        ^ Unexpected 'as'.
    330 |        Member as default
                       ^ Missing semicolon.
    330 |        Member as default
                        ^ Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.
    330 |        Member as default
                          ^ Missing semicolon.
    330 |        Member as default
                           ^ Expected '(end)' and instead saw 'default'.
    330 |        Member as default

Comment: sorry the comment removed the formatting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(As so often) this is is jshint's fault. The line is indeed valid, [ES6 Export syntax](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0#sec-exports) does permit the use of any `IdentifierName` - which includes keywords such as `default` - for the exported name of an `ExportClause`.

I would however discourage from using it. Default exports are much easier to write and read in the `export default` notation, such as

```
var Member = function() {};
export default Member;
// or
export default function Member() {}
```

Admittedly `export default Member;` is not exactly equivalent to `export { Member as default }` but unless you are try to reassign it (you're not, right?) it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: okay thank you! I really just wanted to know since my team is thinking of adopting es6 in a separate branch & this notation came out. Is there a reference for this type of stuff btw?

Comment: I think that 2ality article you found is fine. I haven't read any other docs/tutorials/stuff that I could recommend yet, only went to the spec itself :-)

Comment: How can i export multiple classes with one default class ? I have tried this 

export { Editable , EditableMyTeam };

How to set first class as default ?

Comment: @sijovijayan: You can use multiple exports without problems: `export default Editable, export { EditableMyTeam };`. You can also use `export { Editable as default, EditableMyTeam };`.

Comment: I have just tried the second option, It works !!!, But it showing an ESlint wanning like this " warning  "default" used outside of binding context  block-scoped-var "

Comment: @sijovijayan: That's an [ESlint bug](https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/issues/54) that was fixed 12 days ago :-)