# ES6 syntax confuse about module export

Tags: ecmascript-6

All:

I am pretty new to ES6, when I study ES6 module with this post:

http://www.2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html

**[1]**

there is one line:

```
export { each as forEach };
```

**I wonder if anyone could tell where can I find the usage intro to this specific syntax (especially the curly bracket and `AS` )**

**[2]**

Another confuse is about default export:

**cmod.js**

```
export default var Obj={};
Obj.hello =  function(){
    return "hello";
}
```

**main.js**

```
import hello from "./cmod"
console.log(hello.hello());
```

I wonder why I got error like: :

```
SyntaxError: cmod.js: Unexpected token (1:15)
> 1 | export default var Obj={};
    |                ^
```

But if I move the declaration to a separated line like:

```
var Obj = {}
export default Obj;
Obj.hello =  function(){
    return "hello";
}
```

Then everything works, **why I can not declare a variable and export it?**

Thanks

Comment: *"where can I find the usage intro to this specific syntax "* What exactly do you mean? Do you understand what the syntax does but do not understand why somebody would want to use this?

Comment: *"why I can not declare a variable and export it"* Because `default` exports syntax simply doesn't allow this. Do `export default { hello: ... };` or `var Obj = { ... }; export default Obj`.

Comment: @FelixKling  thanks, for "where can I find...", I do not know what that syntax means, I read some ES6 tutorial, but can not find a post talk about official syntax like { each as forEach },  does this line mean doing a named export and using "name1 as name2 wrapped in curly bracket" syntax to do a name aliasing just like var forEach; forEach = each;?

Comment: From the page you linked to, point 5.2 *"You can also export things under different names"*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ES6 export default AssignmentExpression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24925628/es6-export-default-assignmentexpression)

Comment: Maybe also have a look at [Javascript Es6 default export](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29909466/1048572) on what you *can* do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[1] `export { each as forEach };` this line means, you can export one or more items as objects with or without alias names.

example-1:

```
const MY_CONST = ...;
   function myFunc() {
    ...
}

export { MY_CONST, myFunc };
```

example-2:

```
export { MY_CONST as THE_CONST, myFunc as theFunc };
```